# remove outer quote from json array

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to remove the outer quote from the JSON array. I am using the simple-JSON library for this.
My JSON array contains a string of variable name arrayData like this - `

```
{
    "Name": "stack",
    "xyz": "something"
}, {
    "info": "nothing",
    "set": "get"
}
```

This array is in variable arrayData and I passed this arrayData to JSONArray.

```
JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray();
jsonArray.add(arrayData);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj .put("Info", jsonArray);
```

When I print this **jsonArray**. I am getting the result with double quote inside square bracket like this -

```
["{
"Name": "stack",
"xyz": "something"
}, {
"info": "nothing",
"set": "get"
}"]
```

This is the invalid JSON which I have tried on JSONlint.com
I want to remove the starting double quote inside the square bracket and end double quote. How can I solve this ?? Please suggest any solution for this.

Comment: Your json array is not a json array

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, means??

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, Any mistake I have made here

Comment: a json array starts and ends with square brackets

Comment: also, **assuming** an open and close square brackets around your sample json, it is not an "array of string" but rather an array of objects

Comment: Sorry, Now I have updated my question. That was accidently added.

Comment: I don't see any meaningful update...

Comment: What should I do now? During the creation of string, I have to change something ?

Comment: I have updated the output result of JSON array

Comment: the problem is with the input.  it is not a valid json array or indeed a valid json at all

Comment: if `arrayData` is a `String` that it should first be converted to `JSONObject` or something smilar but it is NOT valid json at all

Comment: what is `arrayData`? how it gets populated?

Comment: Yes, this is not valid JSON array which I have already checked. How can I make it valid? Is there any changes which I can change in string?

Comment: please answer the question in above comment

Comment: arrayData is the string which I have added at the starting of question

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, updated my question again, Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build the json object-by-object.  putting it all in one `String` does not work:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("Name", "stack");
obj.put("xyz", "something");
JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray();
jsonArray.add(obj);
// same for 2nd item
```

Comment: Ok, better I will try this first and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried:

```
   JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
   JsonArray json = (JsonArray) parser.parse("[{\"Name\": \"stack\",\"xyz\": \"something\"}, {\"info\": \"nothing\",\"set\": \"get\"}]");
   System.out.println(json.toString());
```

And the output is:

```
[{"Name":"stack","xyz":"something"},{"info":"nothing","set":"get"}]
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: My expected answer is same as your output. When I am adding string into a JSON array the double quote is coming inside the square bracket. So, how can I apply toString without proper data

Comment: You mean that after second line in my answer you do something like this: json.add("some text")? cause even then I don't see the effect you are talking about. What I get then is: [{"Name":"stack","xyz":"something"},{"info":"nothing","set":"get"},"some text"]

Answer (score -2):

Your input JSON is not valid, and is not an Array. You need braces "[" at start and  "]" end of JSON

```
[{
    "Name": "stack",
    "xyz": "something"
}, {
    "info": "nothing",
    "set": "get"
}]
```

Comment: Yes, I want this output. But, How can I get it?